# Express Router "Cannot GET ..." on browser screen

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to set up a router.get that is in another folder rather than /routes.
When I direct browser to this route, I get "Cannot GET /auth_box" on browser screen.
Either you can't so this, or I'm doing something dumb.

app.js:

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
var auth_box = require('./public/js/download_cs');
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/auth_box', auth_box);
```

download_cd.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/auth_box', function(req, res){
  console.log("/auth_box");
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `app.use(require('pathtoroutefile');` As long as you expose the router in your route file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have the url `/auth_box` twice.
When you use a route, the first argument is the default path for that route, so right now the correct URL would be `/auth_box/auth_box`

In your route, just do

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log("/auth_box");
});
```

As you've already set `/auth_box` in `app.use('/auth_box', auth_box);`

Comment: Yep, I did something dumb!! It's working. Much Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your `download_cd.js` should be like the following. By using, `app.use('/auth_box', auth_box);` your are specifying `/auth_box` as the base path for all the routes in `auth_box`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
router.get('*', function(req, res){ //this matches /auth_box/*
  console.log("/auth_box");
});
router.get('/sample', function(req, res){ //this matches /auth_box/sample
  console.log("/auth_box/sample");
});
module.exports = router;
```